# If x Exceptions in Given Timeframe

Tags: python

I am currently using a counter to flag when 5 exceptions have been raised. Once the threshold is met the script notifies me by sending a Telegram message.

This works ok but I want to introduce a timeframe criteria so that a message is only send if 5 exceptions have been raised in the last 60 minutes.

I am a beginner and struggling to work out how to do it so any help would be appreciated.

```
count = 0

while True:
    try:
        do_stuff()

    except:
        count += 1
        if count >= 5:
            send_message_via_Telegram()
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you simply keep a list of time stamps of the last 5 exceptions. In that case you don't even need the variable `count`, unless you specifically want to know how many exceptions have occured in total. Instead, make sure that the list only ever contains the latest 5 exceptions and then compare the first and last elements and check if the difference is less than one hour.

```
import time
exceptions = []
while True:
    try:
        do_stuff()
    except:
        exceptions.append(time.time())
        if len(exceptions)>5:
            exceptions.pop()
        time_between_endpoints = exceptions[-1] - exceptions[0]
        if (time_between_endpoints < 3600 and len(exceptions)==5):
            send_message_via_Telegram()
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to record the time difference between time at which the first exception was raised and time at which every subsequent exception is raised, then convert it to minutes and check if it's more than 60.

```
import time

count = 0
first_exception_time = None

while True:
    try:
        do_stuff()

    except:
        if count == 0:
            first_exception_time = time.time()
        diff = time.time() - first_exception_time
        count += 1
        if count >= 5 and (diff/60) > 60:
            send_message_via_Telegram()
            break
```

Comment: This checks whether it has been 60 minutes since the code started running, but OP wants to figure out if the last 5 exceptions have occured within the last 60 minutes

Comment: Right, I fixed the answer

Comment: Yes, however it still calculates the current exception time vs. the very first exception that occured. Furthermore, the second comparison will never be `True`. It checks whether *something* modulo 60 is larger than 60, and that will never be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
T_Sec=60*60
count = 0
Sec_done=0
while True:
    Sec+=1
    try:
        do_stuff()
    except:
        count += 1
        if count >= 5 and Sec_done<=T_Sex:
            send_message_via_Telegram()
            break
    time.sleep(1)
```

What I have done is just added 1 to `Sec_done` every second, and if `Sec_done` is less than or equal to `T_Sec`, it gets into the if statement.

I have used `time.sleep(1)` to cause delay of a second in the loop, which would also cause a delay to run `do_stuff` function, you can create a new function to added `sec+=1` and use `threading` to simultaneously run 2 or more function.